# How to add vertex to object face

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I'm struggling to add a vertex to this face. I am hoping to create a pyramid type shape by extending this face to a triangular shape.
I have added an image to show the affect I am trying to achieve, is anybody able to help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press K, and cut along the vertices you're showing, or select two vertices and press J.